# why the app is crashing while retrieving the data from sqlite from same table more than one time

Tags: ios, sqlite

i have a problem with retrieving data with sqlite..
i hav a table called bills(bill_id, bill_name,.......)..
while im retrieving the fields for the 1st time am  not getting any error,
 if am retrieving the data from the same table second time, its giving the following error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

why am getting this exception?

is that the problem of opening and closing of db? for your info im keeping db opened..

please help me..

this is my code to retrieve all fields

-(NSMutableArray *)getBillsList

```
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database);
int success;
NSMutableArray * getBillsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString * sql = @"select * from bill";

sqlite3_stmt * getStatement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &getStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
while (sqlite3_step(getStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    Bills  * bill = [[Bills alloc]init];


        bill.group_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 1)];


        bill.payee_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 2)];


        bill.photo_file = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 3)];


        bill.amount = sqlite3_column_double(getStatement, 4);


        bill.type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 5)];

        bill.due_date = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 6)];

        bill.note = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 7)];

        bill.acno = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 8)];


        bill.remainder_notification = sqlite3_column_int(getStatement, 9);


        bill.payment_type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 10)];

    [getBillsList addObject:bill];
}

success = sqlite3_finalize(getStatement);

if (success == SQLITE_ERROR)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to retrieve from the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    //return NO;
}
else
{
    printf("Successfully retrieved data from database");
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return getBillsList;
```

and this is only for retrieving one field group_name

-(NSMutableArray *)getAllGroups

```
    sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database);
int success;
NSMutableArray * getBillsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString * sql = @"select group_name from bill";

sqlite3_stmt * getStatement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &getStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

while (sqlite3_step(getStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
```

// here am getting the above exception

```
    NSString * str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 1)];

    [getBillsList addObject:str];
}

success = sqlite3_finalize(getStatement);

if (success == SQLITE_ERROR)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to retrieve from the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    //return NO;
}
else
{
    printf("Successfully retrieved data from database");
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return getBillsList;
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libs? If not, I'd recommend you use some lib like [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). And after querying, remember to close the db connection, or use the same connection through queries.

Answer (score -1):

Please Put some image or code....

i assume your problem and give solution
Make Custom class for save and Get data.....for Bill_id also put this code in your appdelegate.m

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath: dbPath])
{

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: yourOriginalpath toPath: dbPath error: NULL] != YES)
        NSAssert2(0, @"Fail to copy database from %@ to %@", yourOriginalpath, dbPath);
}
```